# awk when both delimiter and quotes are used for a field

Tags: awk, csv

I have a file in the following format:

```
field1|field2|field3
field1|"field2|field2"|field3
```

Notice the second row contains double quotes. The string within the double quotes belongs to field 2. How do extract this using awk? I've been googling with no results. I tried this with no luck as well

```
FS='"| "|^"|"$' '{print $2}'
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7804673/escaping-separator-within-double-quotes-in-awk

Comment: See [whats-the-most-robust-way-to-efficiently-parse-csv-using-awk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45420535/whats-the-most-robust-way-to-efficiently-parse-csv-using-awk).

Answer (score 13):

If you have a recent version of `gawk` you're in luck. There's the `FPAT` feature, documented [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Splitting-By-Content.html)

```
awk 'BEGIN {
 FPAT = "([^|]+)|(\"[^\"]+\")"
}
{
 print "NF = ", NF
 for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++) {
    sub(/"$/, "", $i); sub(/^"/, "", $i);printf("$%d = %s\n", i, $i)
 }
}' file

NF =  3
$1 = field1
$2 = field2
$3 = field3
NF =  3
$1 = field1
$2 = field2|field2
$3 = field3
```

Comment: You can replace + with * `FPAT = "([^|]*)|(\"[^\"]+\")"` to handle empty fields, such as `||`

Comment: Brilliant.  However, where I'm using this on comma separated files it doesn't cope with double quotes in the field, so I'm using `FPAT = "([^,]*)|(\"([^\"]|\"\")*\")"`.  For the above with pipe delimiter it would be `FPAT = "([^|]*)|(\"([^\"]|\"\")*\")"`.

Comment: So, what if I _don't_ have FPAT available?

Comment: @musicin3d,  in that case take a look at Sobrique's perl solution

Answer (score 1):

This is something that you get in `csv` - if the delimiter is part of the field, it gets quoted. That suddenly makes the task of parsing it MUCH harder, because you can't just split on a delim.

Fortunately, if `perl` is an option, you have the `Text::CSV` module that handles this case:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use Text::CSV;

my $csv = Text::CSV -> new ( { 'sep_char' => '|' } );

while ( my $row =  $csv -> getline ( *STDIN ) ) {
   print $row -> [1],"\n";
}
```

Could probably condense this to an inline/pipeable if you prefer - something like:

```
perl -MText::CSV -e 'print map { $_ -> [1] ."\n" } @{ Text::CSV -> new ( { 'sep_char' => '|' } ) -> getline_all ( *ARGV )};
```

Answer (score -3):

You may want to format this data with `sed` so it can be parsed by `awk` more easily. for example:

```
$ sed 's/"//g' awktest1.txt 
field1|field2|field3
field1|field2|field2|field3

$ sed 's/"//g' awktest1.txt > awktest2.txt

$ awk 'BEGIN {FS = "|"} ; {print $2}' awktest2.txt 
field2
field2
```

But then again, I don't know the nature of the data you are working with.

Comment: The idea is explicitly to have `field2|field2` as a single field in the second line.