# How to remove duplicates from pipe delimited file using awk with Pipe in Values?

Tags: shell-script, awk, escape-characters

I am trying to remove duplicates based on multiple columns from a pipe delimited file using this [How to remove duplicates based on multiple dynamic columns](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/697161/how-to-remove-duplicates-based-on-multiple-dynamic-columns/697362?noredirect=1#comment1317687_697362)
But I found there are pipes within the values in double quotes like below

```
3|XX|""|2022-04-05T21:39:22.899Z|2022-04-05T21:37:59Z|X7
3|XX|"2025035|6|15|0|0|15|39"|2022-04-05T21:39:22.899Z|2022-04-05T21:37:59Z|X7
```

These 2 rows are duplicates when I check on last column position6 and position 2 but due to pipes in position3 its not working. How to escape the Pipes in double quotes in below code ?

```
$4='2,6'
awk -v c="$4"  -F'|' 'BEGIN{split(c,k,",")} {key=""; for (i in k) key=key FS $(k[i])} !seen[key]++'
```

TIA

Comment: What are the escaping rules of your format? for ex when you have a `|`, `"`, `\n` as part of the data?

Comment: It will be like this for "\"\"" for \

Comment: Use one of the csvkit tools

Comment: @roaima does csvkit handle that kind of escaping rules?

Comment: @Fravadona it handles proper CSV escaping rules, so two comma separated fields of `"item, item",another" "item` would be properly parsed as `item, item` and `another" "item`, but I can't understand what vks009 is trying to show for the escaping rules. It would be much easier if they provided a (well formatted) example in their question

Comment: Delimiter here is pipe and awk is taking into account the pipe in value that are in double quotes as shown in line 2. awk should ignore the pipes within "2025035|6|15|0|0|15|39"

Comment: You can do it with GNU awk, using `FPAT` to define what comes *between* separators - see for example [awk when both delimiter and quotes are used for a field](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/238182/65304)

Comment: Yes, I went through that but not able to replicate it for pipe

Comment: The devil is in the details: You should edit your question for adding an input example that illustrates your quoting rules. From what I understood (inside double-quotes you have `\"` for `"` and  `\\ ` for `\ `), the current answers do not take them into account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With GNU awk for `FPAT`:

```
$ awk -v c='2,6' -v FPAT='([^|]*)|("[^"]*")' 'BEGIN{split(c,k,",")} {key=""; for (i in k) key=key RS $(k[i])} !seen[key]++' file
3|XX|""|2022-04-05T21:39:22.899Z|2022-04-05T21:37:59Z|X7
```

If you could have nested double quotes like `"foo""bar"` then change the FPAT assignment to `FPAT='[^|]*|("([^"]|"")*")'`

See [whats-the-most-robust-way-to-efficiently-parse-csv-using-awk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45420535/whats-the-most-robust-way-to-efficiently-parse-csv-using-awk) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

You could do it in an awk-like way with [Miller](https://miller.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

```
mlr --csv --fs '|' --implicit-csv-header --headerless-csv-output --quote-original filter '
  key = $2.FS.$6; @seen[key] += 1; @seen[key] == 1'
' file
3|XX|""|2022-04-05T21:39:22.899Z|2022-04-05T21:37:59Z|X7
```

(It doesn't seem to be possible to use the exact analogue `!@seen[$6]++` because Miller has [no autoconvert to boolean](https://miller.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference-dsl-differences/#no-autoconvert-to-boolean) nor post-increment operator.)